# Можно ли при помощи flexbox сделать так, чтобы первая колонка была фиксированной ширины, а вторая растягивалась на всю оставшуюся ширину?

Tags: css, flexbox

Можно ли при помощи flexbox сделать так, чтобы первая колонка была фиксированной ширины, а вторая растягивалась на всю оставшуюся ширину?

Answer (score 7):

Конечно можно. Примерно так:

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-content: flex-start;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; border: solid 1px; padding: 3px;">фиксированной ширины</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; border: solid 1px; padding: 3px;">растягивается</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 150px; margin-top: 3px;">
   <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-content: flex-start;">
      <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; border: solid 1px; padding: 3px;">фиксированной ширины</div>
      <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; border: solid 1px; padding: 3px;">и сжимается</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`flex-grow: 0` Запретит левому пытаться отхватить кусок свободного пространства.
`flex-grow: 1` При отсутствии конкурентов позволит правому захватить всё свободное пространство. (В данном случае можно написать любое другое число, отличное от нуля)

`flex-shrink: 0` Не позволит левому скукситься меньше, чем ему надо.
`flex-shrink: 1` Будет сжимать правый вслед за уменьшением общей ширины.

Вот тут полезная статейка http://habrahabr.ru/post/242545/
Ещё где-то встречал толковое руководство, но уже не помню. В общем есть в интернете инфа по этой теме неплохого качества .

Comment: Вот только зачем CSS inline писать?

Comment: @dzhioev Затем, чтобы сразу было ясно какой css у какого элемента. А не выискивать соответствие одного другому. А если ещё что-то уйдёт из зоны видимости? Что, охота крутить туда-сюда?

Answer (score 2):

Да можно, у дочерних дивов нужно установить ширину, для фиксированного, для того кто должен занимать все оставшееся установить свойство *flex: 1 0*, или *flex-grow: 1*

[Сайт с хорошим описанием *display:flex*](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}
.first {
  width: 200px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.last {
  flex: 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item first">Text 1</div>
  <div class="item last">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; //По дефолту
}

.content_sub_one {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.content_sub_two {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content_sub_one">
  text1
  </div>
  <div class="content_sub_two">
  text2
  </div>
</div>
```